# C# list of all files on disk - Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, string, exception, type-conversion

Good morning!

I have a little problem with my program. This program should list all files on C: disk but it throw me following exceptions:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'  ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\aleš\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  15  Active
```

Please, can you help me? This is not my code so I really don't know what to do with it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var paths = Traverse(@"C:\");
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\\test.txt", paths);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> Traverse(string rootDirectory)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> files = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            IEnumerable<string> directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            try
            {
                // The test for UnauthorizedAccessException.
                var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, rootDirectory);
                permission.Demand();

                files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory);
                directories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore folder (access denied).
                rootDirectory = null;
            }

            if (rootDirectory != null)
                yield return rootDirectory;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }

            // Recursive call for SelectMany.
            var subdirectoryItems = directories.SelectMany(Traverse);
            foreach (var result in subdirectoryItems)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!
With regards,
Aleš

Comment: Well yes, you're getting an `IEnumerable<string>`, but `File.WriteAllLines` requires a `string[]` apparently (it sounds like you're targeting an old version of .NET). So you could use `paths.ToArray()`...

Comment: are you missing `.ToArray()`?

Comment: @JonSkeet there is a overload with IEnumerable

Comment: your code works fine on my pc. So as @JonSkeet already said, you should either got to .net Version 4.0 or higher or use ToArray File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\\test.txt", paths.ToArray());

Comment: @mybirthname: Constructor for what? There's a *method overload* for `File.WriteAllLines` taking an `IEnumerable<string>`, but that was introduced in .NET 4.0. Given the error message, my guess is that the OP is targeting .NET 3.5.

Comment: sorry yes overload, I don't know about the verison, but I suppose you are correct.

Comment: @JonSkeet: thank you very much,the problem was old version of .NET.
Please, can I have one more question? This print folders also, but I need only files. Is here any way how to print only files?

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow works. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build up a repository of high quality questions and answers. "Just one more question" really doesn't help that goal. However, you should be able to fix that yourself reasonably easily if you understand your `Traverse` method clearly...

Comment: I am really sorry, I am newbie here but I will keep this on my mind. Anyway, I fixed it already :)